# Prove that $7n^2 + 2n + 3 = O(n^2)$ using the definition of O notation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Prove that $7n^2 + 2n + 3 = O(n^2)$ using the definition of O notation. I need to use two constants and prove that they satisfy the O definition.

I'm new to big O and want to know whether I am approaching the problem the right way. Is below how I prove the problem? If not, what do I need to keep in mind or what should I do differently? I'm basing my answer off of what I've been reading, so I could be way off.

Proof: by the big-oh definition, $T(n)$ is $O(n^2)$  if $T(n) \leq c * n^2$ for some $n \geq n_0$ . Let us check this condition: if $7n^2 + 2n + 3 \leq c * n^2$ then $7 + 2/n^2 + 3/n^2 \leq c.$ Therefore, the big oh condition holds for $n \geq n_0 = 1$ and $c \geq 12 (= 7 + 2 + 3)$

Comment: Look at $n \geq 7.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$f(n) := 7n^{2} + 2n + 3$
for all integers $n \geq 1$.
Then
$f(n)/n^{2} = 7 + 2/n + 3/n^{2}.$
We claim that there is a real 
$M$
such that
$f(n)/n^{2} \leq M$
for large $n$.
But both 
$(2/n)$ and
$(3/n^{2})$
are convergent to zero,
so that
$2/n, 3/n^{2} < 1/2$
for large $n$,
and hence
$7 + (2/n) + (3/n^{2}) < 7 + 1 = 8$
for large $n$.
Letting
$M := 8$
completes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

For all $n \ge 1$, we have $2n \le 2n^2$ and $3 \le 3n^2$. Therefore, $7n^2+2n+3 \le 7n^2+2n^2+3n^2 = 12n^2$.